use os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM) make my main process not work
def __remove_progress_without_lock(self, k):
    import os
    import signal
    if k in self.progress_map:
        p = self.progress_map[k]
        if p.is_alive():
            # p.terminate()
            # print("stop 6")
            # p.join()
            os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            p.join()
            # os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            # p.join()
            exit_code = p.exitcode
            print(f"stop 7 exit_code:{exit_code}")
        del self.progress_map[k]
        print("stop 8")

#---------other code----------------------------------------------
def add_progress(self, k, progress):
    with SingletonProgressRecorder.__lock:
        self.progress_map[k] = progress

def test(para: CreatePara):
    print(para)
    for i in range(para.time_s):
        print(f"{para.sign}: {i}")
        time.sleep(1)
    return para

@app.post("/add")
def add_test(para: AddPara):
    try:
        export_recorder = SingletonProgressRecorder()
        rc_args = (para,)
        p = Process(target=test, args=rc_args)
        export_recorder.add_progress(para.sign, p)
        p.start()
        return {"status": "success", "data": "Process started successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=repr(e))

@app.post("/stop")
def stop_test(para: StopPara):
    print("stop_test")
    try:
        export_recorder = SingletonProgressRecorder()
        export_recorder.remove_progress(para.sign)
        return {"status": "success", "data": "Process stopped successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=repr(e))


I use dict() to store some process and I want to stop an alive process. I use the code terminate() or os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM), but they don't work. The subprocess could not be terminated. Only when I use os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL) it worked. I don't know how to kill the process safe. The problem only occured on linux.

Please try to provide a minimal reproduction of the behavior.

Why not use p.terminate()?
